# JSON mailto URL contains a whitespace

Tags: html, json

There is a space in the URL below that is used to create a mailto link in the body of an email, which will not work. I have tried adding %20 to compensate; however, that does not work. Any suggestion on getting this URL corrected so a user can click on the link as advised in the email? Thank you!

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "8px"
      },
      "txtContent": "@currentField.title"
    },
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Mail",
        "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
        "href": {
          "operator": "+",
          "operands": [
            "mailto:",
            "@currentField.email",
            "?subject=Task status&body=Hello, how is your task coming along?.\r\n---\r\n",
            "@currentField.title",
            "\r\nClick this link for more info. https://somesite.sharepoint.com/Information Technology/Lists/Projects/AllItems.aspx?ID=",
            "[$ID]"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

}

Comment: this might do the trick. <a target='_blank' href="https://somesite.sharepoint.com/Information Technology/Lists/Projects/AllItems.aspx?ID=[$ID]" >link</a>

Comment: @phonemyatt Thank you unfortunately, it did not work. The space remains in the email message so the URL is displayed as https://somesite.sharepoint.com/information. I am continuing to research, maybe concatenating two strings instead..